# How to use `keyof` to create a map

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have the following interface

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
    id: number;
}
```

I want to get the keys of the interface, so that I could then create an enum/map of it, i.e.

```
// somehow create `map` 
// map.name should be 'name'
// map.age should be 'age'
```

Comment: The interface in Typescript is only metadata that is evaluated during compilation and has **no** implementation whatsoever in the final JS. The only way to do it is manually.

Comment: When you say `map.name should be 'name'` you want `map.name` with `name` as Literal Type or you are talking about the value? If its about value it's not possible. See @Thomas comment.

Comment: I want the literal type. I want `map.name` to return the string `name`, not what the name of the object is. So that's not possible?

Comment: Not in the compiled application. You probably could write a script to do that in a preprocessing step; maybe in node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `User` interface exists at compile-time, you can't use that information as a run-time map object. However, you can do the converse.

First create a map object as a template for `User`:

```
const userTemplate = {
    name: '',
    age: 0,
    address: '',
    id: 0
};
```

Now instead of writing out `interface User`, you can use `typeof` on the template to infer a `User` type:

```
type User = typeof userTemplate; 
// equivalent to:
// type User = { name: string; age: number; address: string; id: number; }
```

You can grab the keys and store them in a run-time array:

```
const userKeys = Object.keys(userTemplate);
// ['name', 'age', 'address', 'id']
```

You can also create a union type of the keys at compile-time:

```
type UserKey = keyof User;
// equivalent to:
// type UserKey = 'name' | 'age' | 'address' | 'id'
```

[Try it in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IUser%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20address%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20userTemplate%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20address%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%200%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20User%20%3D%20typeof%20userTemplate%3B%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20equivalent%20to%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20User%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%3B%20age%3A%20number%3B%20address%3A%20string%3B%20id%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20userKeys%20%3D%20Object.keys(userTemplate)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%5B'name'%2C%20'age'%2C%20'address'%2C%20'id'%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20UserKey%20%3D%20keyof%20User%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20equivalent%20to%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20UserKey%20%3D%20'name'%20%7C%20'age'%20%7C%20'address'%20%7C%20'id')

Comment: Smart, very smart. Thanks!

Comment: `keyof` was introduced in TypeScript 2.1, so it's only 4 months old. Very powerful. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/12/07/announcing-typescript-2-1/